# passing data from activity to activity in android

Tags: android

What is the problem with my code :(

This is the sending class:

```
public class Send extends AppCompatActivity {

String message_text;
final static String MSG_KEY = "this.is.the.message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send_layout);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText entryText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    message_text = entryText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(message_text, MSG_KEY);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

this is the receiver:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView theMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theMessage);
    theMessage.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("this.is.the.message"));
}
```

}

the app starts but it does not pass text, just an empty recieving activity ???

Comment: What is the problem? **Be specific**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intent.putExtra(message_text, MSG_KEY);
```

replace with

```
intent.putExtra(MSG_KEY, message_text);
```

Frist argument is NAME , second argument - VALUE

Answer (score 0):

You are using value as key and key as value which is causing this issue.

Change

```
intent.putExtra(message_text, MSG_KEY);
```

to

```
intent.putExtra(MSG_KEY, message_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing `intent.putExtra(MSG_KEY, message_text);` doesn't fix the issue. Check AndroidManifest.xml to make sure that MainActivity is not the launcher otherwise your MainActivity starts before the send class.